# Select SQL Statement in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, recordset

```vb
Sub LogCheck()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim StrSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim AppPath As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    AppPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\ceo.accdb;"
    cn.Open strConnection
    S_ID = Sheets("My").Range("A1").Value
    StrSql = "SELECT * FROM EDO Where ID = ' " & S_ID & " '"
    rs.Open StrSql, cn
    If rs = Null Then
        MsgBox "Record Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Record Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

I am unable to run this code. Its showing error. Please help me out. Thanks!
Here `S_ID` is the data which I would like to search from table & ID is the primary key in the EDO Table.

Comment: Can you add the error that you are getting

Comment: there probably should not be spaces between the `'` and the `"`.  like this: `"SELECT * FROM EDO Where ID = '" & S_ID & "'"` unless your data has a preceding and trailing space.

Comment: Run Time Error 91
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: What line is highlighted in yellow when this breaks?

Comment: try declaring rs as recordset. `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: I added reference & Its working fine but there is error showing. "Type Mismatch" for the statement if rs = NULL then

Comment: look [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246335) on how to load the library

Comment: I added reference & Its working fine but there is error showing. "Type Mismatch" for the statement if rs = NULL then. How can we check if rs contain any record or not.

Comment: What is the type of the `ID` field in the database?

Comment: type of the ID field in the database is string

Comment: I guess you have excessive spaces around concatenation `... ' " & S_ID & " '"`. Also you've declared `Dim rs As Object`, thus within conditions computations the equality operator `is` is acceptable for objects, but not equality sign `=`. Generally you might use `If rs is Nothing ...`, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you may detect if the recordset is empty checking [`.EOF` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821459.aspx):

```vb
Sub TestIfRecordFound()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object

    strConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source='C:\ceo.accdb';"
    strID = Sheets("My").Range("A1").Value
    strQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM EDO WHERE ID = '" & strID & "';"

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)

    If objRecordSet.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Record Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Record Found"
    End If

    objConnection.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If Id is numeric than the sql should be:

```
StrSql = "SELECT * FROM EDO WHERE Id = " & S_ID
```

You also did not define S_ID, so it will be handle as a variant here. If you still get an error, you might have to make it "& CStr(S_ID)".

Comment: Here wdate is current date & W_Date is the field in the table with Date/Time data type. but its showing record not found as there are 10 records existing in the table.


    StrSql = "SELECT * FROM ceo WHERE wDate = " & CDate(W_Date) '
    If objRecordSet.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Record Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Record Found"
    End If'

Comment: Date fields in an access DB contain date and time, so your select will not work unless all dates were stored with just the date. You probably need to modify you select as follows: "SELECT * FROM ceo WHERE " & CDate(Format(wDate,"DD/MM/YYYY")) & " = " & CDate(W_Date). You might also have to convert both sides of the equal sign to string by using CStr.

Comment: Its showing error type mismatch.
StrSql = "SELECT * FROM ceo WHERE " & CDate(Format(wDate, "MM/DD/YYYY")) & " = " & CDate(W_Date)

Comment: Try: "SELECT * FROM ceo WHERE #" & CStr(CDate(Format(wDate, "MM/DD/YYYY"))) & "# = #" & CStr(CDate(W_Date))) & "#"

Comment: This one also showing same error. May I store date as string in database table.

Comment: Are you saying the date is a string in the table? If so, you would have to change the format of the select to match the format in the table, and you'd have to replace the "#" with single quotes ( ' ).